# How can I see the app running in my browser?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, virtual-machine

following instructions on Getting Started of the Docker Documentation, I built this docker image and it is running on my VM ubuntu. But I'm stuck on how to viewing the app on my browser. I got the VM private IP specified, any advice on how to connect to it?

```
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

Comment: Please also add the command line you use to launch the container from the image, it has to use `-p/--publish` or `-P/--publish-all` to bind ports. Then `docker container ls` should give you the binded port fort container's 3000 (or you already know it because of explicit port mapping), then just go to `<VM's IP>:<binded port>`

Comment: Thank you Zigarn. It actually worked. After launching the container with: 
docker run -dp 3000:3000 image-name
I did the following on my browser:
<VM's IP>:<binded port>
and it worked.  I thought at first I need to change Dockerfile Expose part, but it worked just fine. Many thanks again.

Comment: @amiodata you should accept the answer of zigarn

Comment: How? Zigran made a comment, he needs to write it in the answer section first I guess.